# Ansible - Target only one host based on output

Tags: ansible

My goal is to perform tasks only one host based on the output during a run. Using `--limit` is therefor not possible.

A shell script is executed on 3 nodes, which returns a boolean.

```
ok: [localMulti3] => {
    "variable": {
        ...
        "stdout": "false",
        ...
    }
}
ok: [localMulti2] => {
    "variable": {
        ...
        "stdout": "false",
        ...
    }
}
ok: [localMulti1] => {
    "variable": {
        ...
        "stdout": "true",
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I perform tasks on only on `localMulti3` or `localMulti2` during Ansible runtime?

Comment: Do you need to perform a task on every host that has `variable.stdout == false`?

Comment: Only one host. And not 'random'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** Update **
The answer that works, is idempotent and quite easy to understand.

On node 2 and 3 perform:

`$: touch /tmp/hi`

```yaml
        - stat:
            path: /tmp/hi
          register: me

        - set_fact:
            run_on: "{{ item }}"
          loop: "{{ play_hosts }}"
          when: 
            - run_on is undefined
            - hostvars[item].me.stat.exists
          run_once: true

        - shell: echo
          when: inventory_hostname == run_on
```

Old answer below:

Alright, it's done. This is not a pretty the method, but it get's the job done. It's a freaking bitc*h because you cannot simply target hosts in a play, or set global variables for hosts in a role.

One thing the hosts have in common is the final number. It's either 1, 2 or 3. And it's possible to set variables for others hosts in a play.

Hope I can save another person with this someday.

Here we go:

```
- hosts:
      - node1
      - node2
      - node3

  tasks:
    - name: some command to check on host for TRUE or false
      shell: somecommand
      register: commando

    - name: set fact where stat is false
      set_fact:
        theCheck: present
      when: commando.stat.exists == false

    - name: echo the hostnames, for convience and shorter naming
      shell: hostname
      register: hn
      changed_when: false

    # First host check
    - name: check if 1st node is applicable
      set_fact:
        firstNode: True
      when: "{{ hn.stdout | last | last }} == 1 and theCheck is defined"

    - name: set a fact for all hosts in play
      set_fact:
        checkFirst: "{{ hostvars[groups['all'][0]]['firstNode'] | default(False) }}"

    - name: perform task if applicable on first host
      shell: echo
      when: firstNode is defined

    # Second host check
    - name: check if 2nd node is applicable host
      set_fact:
        secondNode: present
      when: "{{ hn.stdout | last | last }} == 2 and theCheck is defined and checkFirst == False"

    - name: set a fact for all hosts in play
      set_fact:
        checkSecond: "{{ hostvars[groups['all'][1]]['secondNode'] | default(False) }}"

    - name: perform task on second node if applicable
      shell: echo
      when: secondNode is defined

    # Third host check
    - name: perform task on third node if applicable
      shell: echo
      when: "{{ hn.stdout | last | last }} == 3 and mongoSlaves is defined and checkSecond == False"
      register: thirdNode

    ### EXTRA
    - name: perform task on first node if not selected
      shell: another echo
      when: "{{ hn.stdout | last | last }} == 1 and firstNode is not defined"

    - name: perform task on secondary node if not selected
      shell: another echo
      when: "{{ hn.stdout | last | last }} == 2 and secondNode is not defined"

    - name: perform task on third node if not selected
      shell: another echo
      when: "{{ hn.stdout | last | last }} == 3 and thirdNode is not defined"
```

Answer (score 0):

To execute a task on specific host you can check `inventory_hostname` variable:

```
- shell: echo ok
  when: variable.stdout | bool == false and inventory_hostname == 'localMulti3'
```

Update (with info from comment) – to execute task only once use `run_once`:

```
- shell: echo ok
  when: variable.stdout | bool == false
  run_once: true
```

Comment: With this method I need to staticly insert a hostname. Is it possible to tell ansible: Pick the first machine, where the statement is false?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: This will run the task on the first host, which is 'true'.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `register` result of a playbook action would be saved. So In another action this registered variable can be accessed.

```
- name: shell_script
  script: shell_script.sh
  register: variable

- shell: echo
  when: variable.stdout == 'false'
```

Comment: Yes. But the second task is performed on both hosts which are false. I only desire one host which is false. I also do not want to include it statically e.g. inventory_hostname == 'localMulti3'

Comment: In Ansible scope of each defined variable is restricted to the host that the play is running on. You need some kind of a global variable which Ansible does not provide because it is built to run actions simultaneously on many servers. A global variable would lead to a race condition.

Comment: So my goal is not possible to achieve in any way? And group_vars/all can be a global variable?